# Why GetCaretPos returns different from GetTextExtentPoint32 for a remote edit

Tags: winapi, apimonitor

The edit is in a different program (DPI unaware). My program is trying to get the text width.

```
    std::wstring text = L"1234";
    HWND edit = 0x04AC1BF0;
    // AttachThreadInput
    // ...
    auto ret1 = ::GetCaretPos(&pt1); // pt1 => {x=1 y=1}
    // Set text to "1234" here
    // ...
    ::Sleep(3000);
    auto ret2 = ::GetCaretPos(&pt2); // pt2 => {x=25 y=1}

    HDC hdc = GetDC(edit);
    auto hFont = (HFONT)SendMessage(edit, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);
    auto oldObj = SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
    CSize size1;
    auto ret3 = GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, text.c_str(), text.size(), &size1); // size1 => {cx=32 cy=16}
    CRect rect1;
    DrawText(hdc, text.c_str(), text.size(), &rect1, DT_CALCRECT | DT_NOPREFIX | DT_SINGLELINE); // {LT(0, 0) RB(32, 16)  [32 x 16]}
    SelectObject(hdc, oldObj);
    ReleaseDC(edit, hdc);
```

So `GetTextExtentPoint32` behaves the same as DrawText. They both returns width as `32`. Result of `GetCaretPos` changes from `{1, 1}` to `{25, 1}`, means the width is `24`.

DPI is 150% on my computer. Those APIs return values **don't change** if I set DPI it to 100%. So I think it is not because of DPI impact.

What's the relationship of those 2 APIs?

---

With API monitor tool, I can see the program itself calls GetTextExtentPoint32A and returns `[24, 12]`. That behaves similar to GetCaretPos.

How could I get the same result as the target process itself?

---

Things become more interesting now! If I create the font and select it again, then `GetTextExtentPoint32` returns `[24, 12]`!

```
LOGFONT font = { 0 };
::GetObject(hFont, sizeof(LOGFONT), &font);
hFont = ::CreateFontIndirect(&font);
auto oldObj = ::SelectObject(hdc, hFont);
```

If I DrawText to the edit before recreation, I can see the font is `Bold`, but after font recreation and redrawn, it looks `Normal`.

Could you explain this?

Comment: From GetCaretPos (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcaretpos) documentation: This API does not participate in DPI virtualization.

Comment: @user2120666 It doesn’t change if I use 100% or 150%.

Comment: Sure, because it doesnt support DPI virtualization,

Comment: I don't know why people focus on DPI, this is not about DPI, they are still different even you use 100% DPI!

Comment: But in your question says: Those APIs return the same if I change it to 100%.

Comment: @user2120666 I mean the same as before, not the same as each other.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcaretpos) for `GetCaretPos` says

> This API does not participate in DPI virtualization.

On the other hand, the other two functions that you mention do participate in DPI virtualization.

Comment: 24*150% != 36, the other 2 functions return 32. I’d like to know the reason. They are different even with 100% DPI.

Comment: Calculation is more complex than that. Enable DPI awareness in your app and see that my answer is correct.

Comment: @user1633272: And where you get value 36 ? I dont see this MAGIC number in your question.

Comment: @user2120666 sorry, just typed in mobile, I mean 24*150% is 36, the other 2 functions return 32, they are still different, I will try DIP awareness, currently it is a unit test.

Comment: Currently my program is DPI awareness and the another program which hosts the edit is DPI unaware, still get the same result.

Comment: If I test with text '1234567890', then GetCaretPos returns 61, GetTextExtentPoint32  returns 80, the coefficient roughly 133%. Is it because the font size is actually 6, but GetTextExtentPoint32  uses 8?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The edit is in another process (DPI unaware), with API monitor tool I can see GetTextExtentPoint32A returns [24 x 12] in its process, however, no matter I set DPI to 100% or I enable DPI awareness for my program, it always returns [32 x 16]. I also tried to select the same font as WM_GETFONT to DC, doesn't help.

Comment: "the coefficient roughly 133%". This discrepancy is caused by pixel rounding. When opening font its height is rounded to whole pixels. Next it's width (advace distance) is rounded to whole pixels again. Some fonts are widened when used with small height to improve legibility. For these using bigger heights gives smaller relative widths. If you change DPI for primary monitor logoff and login to propagate changes to all DPI unaware aplications

Answer (score 0):

'WM_GETFONT' return value is a handle to the font used by the control, or NULL if the control is using the system font.
You can have a try like it:

```
HFONT hFont =（HFONT）SendMessage（edit，WM_GETFONT，0,0）; 
if（NULL == hFont）
hFont =（HFONT）GetStockObject（SYSTEM_FONT）;
```